# Calculating percent of area changed between 2 time steps using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, statistics, change-detection, arcgis-9.2

I need an image to show how many percent of area in class has been changed between 2 years

For example, in output image, red is the area that has been changed 50%, blue is 35-45%, green is <35% etc.

How can I extract this image in ArcGIS Desktop 9.2 step by step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the [Con function](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Conditional_evaluation%3a_Con) in the Raster calculator to detect changes (the rasters should have the same pixel size and extent):

```
change = con(2007raster = 2000raster, 1, 0)
```

(if the value of a cell is equal in the both rasters, 1 will be assigned to that cell in the output, but if the value has changed then the output cell will be 0).

You will get 0-1 raster of the changed pixels.
Then you can convert 2000 [raster to polygons](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=raster_to_polygon_%28conversion%29) and use [Zonal statistics](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=zonal_statistics) to compute how many changed pixels are inside each class (using SUM).

In the polygons attribute table you can compute the area of each class and then get change percentage as

```
pixel area * number of changed pixels * 100 / class area
```

If you take entire area of each class you can plot a chart. If you compute it for every polygon you can then set a symbology for percentages and get a map.